# Какие теги на фав иконку нужно сформировать, чтобы добавленный сайт отображался как ВК или Яндекс?

Tags: вёрстка, shortcuts, favicon

Собственно вопрос.

Нужно, чтобы добавленный сайт Indokitay отображался иконкой побольше, чем сейчас. Как Погода или Маркет.  В идеале - вообще как ВК, без названия ниже.

Как этого добиться?

[image: t]

Comment: Откуда он берет название Indokitay я не понимаю тоже. В манифесте его не прописано (было прописано по-русски, но убрал - толку ноль)

Answer (score 1):

## Простой способ - через HTML-код страницы:

```html
<meta name="yandex-tableau-widget"
content="logo=http://sitename.tld/images/logo.png, color=#ffffff, feed=feed.json" />
```

Где:

`name` — наименование мета-тега yandex-tableau-widget.

`content` — описание логотипа, цвета виджета и нотификаторов в формате:

```
content="logo=logo.png, color=#ffffff, feed=feed.json"
```

где:

`logo` — абсолютный путь к файлу логотипа (должен быть закодирован URLencoded);

`color` — цвет фона виджета (в шестнадцатеричном коде HEX);

`feed` — это необязательный атрибут, который обозначает путь к файлу feed.json с описанием нотификаторов. Если не указан, виджет отображается без нотификаторов. Путь должен быть закодирован URLencoded.

#### Более сложный - через файл манифеста

Подробности [на странице с документацией.](https://yandex.ru/dev/browser/tableau/doc/dg/concepts/create-widget-docpage/)

Там же описано как вывводить на виджет разные уведомления.

Comment: Манифест есть, но оттуда он не берет изображения

Comment: @VostokSisters, скорее всего дело в том, что вы не закодировали ссылку на файл: `<ссылка на файл логотипа, закодированная URLencoded>`. Так же, возможно, что ваш логотип не подходит под требования к логотипам. (посмотрите на странице с доками в низу под катом примеры). Попробуйте сделать логотип квадратным - 120 x 120 (возможно браузер видит, что слишком много прозрачного фона).